# Quantize scale in D3JS

Tags: javascript, html, charts, d3.js

I work with D3JS and I want an axis in x with this kind of values : 125, 250, 500, 1000 ... So multiply by 2 my values each time.

So I tried a [Quantize Scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-quantize) like this:

```
var qScale = d3.scale.quantize(2)
              .domain([0, 8000])
              .range([0, 500]);
```

And I create my axis like that :

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(qScale);
```

But when I'm calling the axis with that code :

```
svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + (ChartHeight - padding) + ")")
           .attr("class", "axis")
           .call(xAxis);
```

I have the following error :

Object doesn't support property or method 'rangeBand' (I develop on Visual Studio 2012)

Any idea ?

EDIT: here the full code [code](http://jsfiddle.net/h2juD/1/)

Comment: As it says in the error message. The quantize scale doesn't have a `rangeBand` method.

Comment: Yes I understand, but I never call the rangeBand method

Comment: We would need to see your complete code before being able to help you further.

Comment: I don't have so much code before the code I pasted on my post, I have just created my svg and some variables ...

Comment: Well, something is calling `rangeBand` somewhere. It's not in the code you've posted, so it must be somewhere else.

Comment: Here you can see the entire code http://jsfiddle.net/h2juD/

All happend in initAxes methods

Comment: This looks like a D3 bug to me. You should open an issue for this.

Comment: range([0, 500). Array start marker but no array end marker. Is it a typo made when writing the code on stackoverflow or was it in the original code?

Comment: Yes it's just an error on Stackoverflow, sorry. I edit my post to link the full code on jsfiddle

Comment: I posted an issue on GitHub here https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1367. "d3.svg.axis does not currently support quantize scales" so he said to use Ordinal Scales but we can't use mathematical function (wich I think is the best in my case) with the kind of scale.